# How to associate or link tables together using CakePHP 3.5?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm using the latest version - CakePHP 3.5

What I need is to be able to link 2 tables, **jobs** and **types**. The main table is **jobs** and I'm trying to make an **association** by linking them. There is no problem retrieving data from **jobs** table. Take a look on index.ctp file where the span with the green class is located. So, I get the following **notice** when I try to join both tables.

> Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Jobs\index.ctp, line 10]

*Here are all files I'm using...*

**JobsController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;
use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;

class JobsController extends AppController 
{
public $name = 'Jobs'; 

 /*
  *Default Index Method
  */
 public function index()
 {
    //Route Connection to Controller Method
    $this->loadComponent('Paginator');
    $jobs = $this->Paginator->paginate($this->Jobs->find());
    $this->set(compact('jobs'));

     //Set Query Options
     $options = array(
        'order' => array('Jobs.created' => 'desc'),
         'limit' => 10           
        );

     //Get Job Info
     $jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all', $options);



    $this->set('jobs', $jobs);   
 }
}
```

**JobsTable.php**

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class JobsTable extends Table
{
    public $name = 'Jobs';
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');
        $this->belongsTo('Types'); 
    }

}
```

**index.ctp**

```
<h3>Latest Job Listings</h3>
<ul id="listings">
    <?php foreach($jobs as $job) : ?>

    <li>
        <div class="type">
            <span class="green"><?php echo $job->Types->name; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            <h5><?php echo $job->title; ?> (<?php echo $job->city; ?>, <?php echo $job->state; ?>)</h5>
            <span id="list_date">
                <small><?php echo $job->created->format('F jS h:i A'); ?></small>
            </span>
            <p><?php echo $this->Text->truncate($job->description, 250, array('ellipsis' => '...', 'exact' => false)); ?>
                <?php echo $this->Html->link('Read More',array('controller' => 'jobs', 'action' => 'view', $job->id)) ?></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

I've been spending almost a whole day researching and trying to figure this out on my own but no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to use `contain` so that Cake knows which associations to include in the results.  https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data

Comment: I tried  `$jobs = $this->Jobs->find('all', $options)->contain(['Types']);` but no better results. Any ideas?

Comment: BelongsTo associations on entities are *singular* and *lowercase*. So it would be `$job->type->name`, but you still have to use contains.

Comment: @cgTag how can I use the contain on the JobsController.php file?

Comment: If you answer with the second comment you made, I will up vote it. That was it. The problem was with the entity. Apreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define paginated associations and options in the controller using the `$paginate` property.

```
class JobsController extends AppController {
     public $paginate = [
        'contain'=>['Types'],
        'order'=>['Jobs.created' => 'desc'],
        'limit'=>10
     ];

     public function index() {
           $jobs = $this->paginate($this->Jobs);
           $this->set(compact('jobs'));
     }
}
```

*BelongsTo* associations are attached to entities as *singular* and *lowercase* properties. So you would read it like this `$job->type->name`.

You can save yourself time in the future by using the bake feature to create your models and controllers.

```
bin/cake bake all Types
bin/cake bake all Jobs
```

This would have generated controllers for `Jobs` that used pagination with a `Types` contains, and it would have also generate entities that had phpDoc annotations showing you what the associations are named on the entities.